# VS1053 - How to play a tone without it fading out?

Tags: arduino, audio-player

I'm using the Adafruit Music Maker Shield and an Arduino Uno to generate tones.  One problem I have is that when I play a tone, the volume automatically fades out.  I'd like to have a constant tone that doesn't fade out.  I tried calling `midi_note_on` every time in `loop()`, but that creates a nasty sound instead of a nice constant tone.  Does anyone know any solutions?

Also note, this is what `midi_note_on` looks like

```
void midi_note_on(uint8_t chan, uint8_t n, uint8_t vel) {
  if (chan > 15) return;
  if (n > 127) return;
  if (vel > 127) return;

  VS1053_MIDI.write(MIDI_NOTE_ON | chan);
  VS1053_MIDI.write(n);
  VS1053_MIDI.write(vel);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe also ask this on the Adafruit Forums, you will likely get help from the engineers who built the board.